# Executing laravel commands in cron as a shell command

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel

I'm using cPanel to create a cron like so :

```
* * * * * /home/elsdqscy/folder/update_db.sh > update_db.txt
```

Inside my shell file I have :

```
#!/bin/bash

cd folder && php artisan migrate:fresh --seed --force
```

This should work, knowing that the command `/home/elsdqscy/folder/update_db.sh` works in the terminal.

I do get this error in the output file:

```
In ArgvInput.php line 246:
                                           
  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  

Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the full path inside your shell file as well, like so:

```
cd folder && /usr/bin/php artisan migrate:fresh --seed --force
```

Answer (score 0):

**Running The Scheduler**
[laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling)

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you try

```
* * * * * cd /home/elsdqscy/folder/update_db.sh > update_db.txt
```